# Feeding a custom wxs file to CPackWIX

Tags: cmake, wix, windows-installer, cpack

We are venturing in the idea to port our WiX based `msi` generation to `CPackWIX`, for our CMake projects.

It seems that the idea behind `CPackWIX` is to use `heat.exe` to create an installer that contains exactly the file present in the install directory. Is it possible to feed a custom `wxs` file instead?

The idea would be to then leverage the CPack integration in our development environment, i.e. the `package` target, while keeping complete control regarding the WiX descriptions used to create the `msi` installer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `CPACK_WIX_TEMPLATE` variable for that.

I have a custom wxs file for my installer that includes a custom wxi file.
In my default installers I do it the following way:

```
install(TARGETS yourTarget EXPORT "${PROJECT_NAME}${PROJECT_VERSION}"
    COMPONENT AppBinaries
    LIBRARY DESTINATION bin
    RUNTIME DESTINATION bin CONFIGURATIONS Release)

# this file is copied and renamed to main.wxs by CPack
set(CPACK_WIX_TEMPLATE   "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/packageInstallerCPack.wxs.in")
set(CPACK_WIX_UI_REF     "WixUI_FeatureTree")
set(CPACK_WIX_EXTENSIONS "WixUtilExtension")

configure_file("${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/packageDefinesCPack.wxi.in" "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/packageDefinesCPack.wxi" @ONLY)
set(CPACK_WIX_CANDLE_EXTRA_FLAGS "-I${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}") # for packageDefinesCPack.wxi to work
set(CPACK_WIX_LIGHT_EXTRA_FLAGS  "-loc" "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/AdditionalWixUI_en-us.wxl") # for localization to work, not needed now, but who knows

include(CPack)
include(CPackWIX)

cpack_add_component(AppBinaries DISPLAY_NAME "Binaries" DESCRIPTION "${CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME} Binaries")
```

To build my MSI package I use `cpack -C Release -G WIX`.